# get UINavigationBar reference from NSObject class

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, nsobject

I want to call `popToRootViewController` method from class that is not extending `UIViewController`, but I can't get reference for `navigationController` from it. Is there any way to do that? escaping solution with implementing delegate to `viewController` implementing that method.

For example I want my class named `MyClass : NSObject` to call `popToRootViewController`. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by NSObject class? Is it a subclass of NSObject?

Comment: if you know the location of where your `UINavigationController` is in the view-hierarchy, you can hardcode to reach it from everywhere, based on the `UIWindow` instance's `rootViewController` property – but that would be a poor way in view of future maintaining.

Comment: I mean this @interface MyClass : NSObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get access to your navigation controller, you can do something like:

```
UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;
```

And then you can call

```
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for. Works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get storyboard from same class?

Comment: You can access to your storyboard everywhere by calling 
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle: nil];